# How to insert a new column in a spark dataframe with values from m to n where m and n could be chosen indpendently in Pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to insert a new column in my pre-existing data frame, which I actually want to be used as a key. I want to choose first value of the key myself, and the key shall extend till the length of the datagram, Note that I want the values to be consecutive. For example :

```
--------------
|    Name    |
--------------
|     A      |
|     B      |
|     C      |
|     D      |
--------------
```

Transformed Dataframe:

```
-------------------------
|    Name    | df_key   |
-------------------------
|     A      |   60     |
|     B      |   61     |
|     C      |   62     |
|     D      |   63     |
-------------------------
```

In the above example: I want to 60 to be a variable and the remaining keys should extend till the length of the Dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `row_number` and add `n-1`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

n=60
df.withColumn('df_key',F.row_number().over(Window.orderBy(F.lit(0)))+(n-1)).show()
```

---

```
+----+------+
|Name|df_key|
+----+------+
|   A|    60|
|   B|    61|
|   C|    62|
|   D|    63|
+----+------+
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **`row_number`** window function by ordering on **`monotonically_increasing_id`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----+
#|Name|
#+----+
#|   A|
#|   B|
#|   C|
#|   D|
#+----+

from pyspark.sql.window import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
w=Window.orderBy(monotonically_increasing_id())
constant=60
df.withColumn("df_key", constant + row_number().over(w)).show()
#+----+------+
#|Name|df_key|
#+----+------+
#|   A|    60|
#|   B|    61|
#|   C|    62|
#|   D|    63|
#+----+------+
```